# Nginx - how to redirect for the index/root page but maintain all other paths?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have an nginx kubernetes pod/ingress hosting a website at `example.com`, right now it's a relatively unstyled home page. I have some other paths which need to persist (ie: `example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` is used by a mobile application to verify app links... That file needs to stay available there (it is impossible to host the file at the redirected domain). I'd like any other requests, specifically to `example.com` to redirect to `different.site.com`.

I have an html redirect working, it's not ideal due to the delay in the redirect.

I put in a permanent redirect using k8s annotations

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
       rewrite ^/ https://different.site.com permanent;
```

Which worked generally, but also any requests for the assetlinks file were redirected, breaking the app links.

I've been playing with the Ingress rules, changing the `pathType` value from Prefix to Exact to see if that gives desired results, but so far no luck.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: applinks-ingress
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
       rewrite ^/ https://different.site.com permanent;
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    secretName: applinks-tls
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Exact
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: applinks-service
            port:
              number: 80
      - pathType: Exact
        path: /.well-known/assetlinks.json
        backend:
          service:
            name: applinks-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

If anyone knows how to do this, I'd be very appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `location` block for this. However, I am not familiar with how this YML configuration is transformed into nginx configuration.

In nginx configuration the block looks like this:

```
location = / {
    return 301 https://different.example.com;
}
```

If you cannot implement the `location` block, then you can use this rewrite:

```
rewrite ^/$ https://different.example.com permanent;
```

`^` means matching start of the string, while `$` means matching end of the string. Overall this means that only `/` location is matches by the regex.

Comment: I will try that regex(?) out at some point - seems like it would work. I implemented an html redirect for now, it's not pretty but it works. I had read about the location blocks, and briefly looked into it, but I also wasn't sure how to implement them in a k8s config.. I think it may be creating/mounting a config file at a specific path in the deployment, but I didn't test it out.